# android : set margin between buttons with LayoutParams

Tags: android, button, layoutparams

I want to automatically generate buttons vertically with a bottom margin of 20px between buttons. I try to set margin with a LayoutParams object, without success.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/regions_search"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dip"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ...

    for (Region region : regionsList) {

        //create new button     
        Button button = new Button(mContext);

        //set infos
        int id = Integer.parseInt(Long.toString((Long) region.getId()));        button.setId(id);
        button.setText(region.getName() + "( " + region.getStores_nb() + " )");

        //Layoutparams setting
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 20);

        button.setLayoutParams(params);

        myLinear.addView(button);

        }
```

As you can see on image, there is no space between images. Someone knows why ?
Thank you !
[image]

Comment: Why you use FrameLayout ? XML file is in LinearLayout .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try this:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) button.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.bottomMargin += 20;
button.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Comment: Thank you ! All of you give me the same answer, but you were the first to post ! Thank you ~

Comment: please watch this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16552811/set-a-margin-between-two-buttons-programmatically-from-a-linearlayout?noredirect=1#comment23779639_16552811

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` instead of `FrameLayout.LayoutParams`, as in your xml you are using `LinearLayout`..

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Comment: Cata was faster than you, sorry. Thank you for your help